# Error while sending email using our own server: Sender is probably forged (SPF Softfail)

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, spf

I have an email account from our own server and I can't send any emails and I'd appreciate any help with fixing it.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Sender is probably forged (SPF Softfail)
```

Our mail server is at `mailserver.domain.com`

My email adres is `my.name@domain.com`
DNS - `Text (TXT)` setting of domain.com is like this:

```
v=spf1 mx ip4:<IP of mailserver> mx:mailserver.domain.com ~all
```

Mailserver uses port 587

I authenticate using full my.name@domain.com user when receiving and sending messages.

I'm using Outlook and we're using Exchange 2003 and GIF MailEssentials.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably being generated by your GFI MailEssentials and not Exchange.  The NDR should tell you what the generating server is.  It's been a while since I worked with that product, but check the different policies in MailEssentials.

As a test, you might try having Exchange send directly to the Internet via DNS lookup.  You can create a specific send connector for just the address space of the recipient you are testing with.